# How can I kill an application after a specific amount of time?

Tags: time, kill

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically close application after custom time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19783/automatically-close-application-after-custom-time)

I want to stop/kill my totem player after a specific amount of time. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a simple command. Once Totem is running, open up the terminal and enter the following line:

```
$ sleep n && totem --quit
```

Where *n* is the number of seconds you want to have elapsed before Totem is closed.

**Explanation of the command**

This is a very simple command, and if you want to learn more about using the terminal you should consider reading a **bash** tutorial, like [this one](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial).

The `sleep n` command waits until *n* seconds have elapsed and then the next command can be run.

Writing `&&` after it tells the terminal to run another command as soon as the previous is finished, which is why I have written `totem --quit` after it.

You can do many more actions and not just quitting. Many applications in linux have a command line interface, which allow you to do this. To see what actions you can do on them through their interface, it is a good idea to check its manual, by running in a terminal `$ man <application>`; or help text, which is usually shown by running in a terminal `$ <application> --help`.

Comment: Totem was just an example. If I replace totem with the application name, will that work?

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain this, but yes - as I wrote - any command after the `&&` will do. If the application didn't have a command line interface, you could write `killall <application>` instead of `totem --quit`.

Answer (score 3):

I've found an alternative answer with another command.

**Step 1.** Find the process id.

```
haris@asylum:~$ ps -e | grep totem
7315 ?        00:00:30 totem
```

**Step 2.** Give the time at which to kill it.

```
haris@asylum:~$ at 11.30pm
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> kill 7315
at> <EOT>
job 8 at Sun Oct  2 07:30:00 2011
```

Where EOT refers to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.